# Do i need an anti-virus program on my VPS

Tags: security, windows-server-2012

Lets say my VPS only runs IIS and Sql Server, nothing else. Do I need an anti-virus program? in another word is it possible to catch a virus without browsing the internet and install random stuffs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of anti-malware software is debatable.  Some people say that there is no need for any anti-malware software at all.

Here is one very different view: For a virtual private server (also known as a virtual machine), you might want to be running even more anti-malware software: run anti-malware software on the virtual machine, and also on the computer that is running the "virtual machine" software.

There is no guarantee that IIS is bug-free.  (In fact, many versions of IIS have been particularly buggy, even more than competing solutions.)  It is entirely believable that anti-malware software might notice the results of a network-based attack that takes advantage of a weakness built into IIS.  Therefore, installing anti-malware software would seem to be prudent.

Now, will installing the anti-malware software guarantee your protection?  Not 100%.  [Mikko Hypponen's "Why Antivirus Companies Like Mine Failed to Catch Flame and Stuxnet"](http://www.wired.com/2012/06/internet-security-fail/) states, "What this means is that all of us had missed detecting this malware for two years, or more. That’s a spectacular failure for our company, and for the antivirus industry in general." ... "The truth is, consumer-grade antivirus products can’t protect against targeted malware created by well-resourced nation-states with bulging budgets."

So installing anti-malware software is not a definite way to be fully protected from any possible attack.  However, it goes often help against many attacks, and is widely considered to be a sensible course of action to take.  So is installing other defenses, like a network-based firewall.  Sometimes some of these defenses may overlap.  Some people may say that some of the defenses aren't needed.  There's a wide variety of opinions, even amongst industry professionals and others that many people consider to be experts.  So it's a matter of making an intelligent, sensible decision that you're comfortable with, rather than having just one answer.

With all that said let me provide a simple, straightforward answer to one of your questions.  If you browse the Internet and install stuff, that is one way that an attacker can gain control over a computer.  There are other ways, too.  So, to answer your question with a single-word answer:

> "in another word is it possible to catch a virus without browsing the internet and install random stuffs?"

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

@TOOGAM's is great for may common uses of VPS systems in particular, but for a more general/traditional perspective of server security issues, I'll put this here.

Short answer, yes, as a general rule, any windows OS should be equipped with an anti-malware platform. Unless you are using a completely stripped down, heavily monitored, no-GUI system in an enterprise environment, there is just too much surface area. These things are all now possible with newer windows servers (not trying to slight MS), but are not common for VPS deployments.

You are correct, in that servers face a different set of attack vectors than do end-user workstations (which is mostly "passive" Trojans), but differences actually make it worse than better, because server attacks are "active", driven by the opponent, and are non-persistent, in that the illicit operator may not be doing anything detectable.

A server hack will generally follow one of several flows depending on what degree of targeting is involved, automation available, and what systems are being exploited. Universally though, unlike workstations, it involves attacking service software.

[Remote administration systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_administration) (RAS) like SSH, telnet, VNC. RemoteDesktop, etc are an attractive target. Once identified, the attacker will attempt to leverage exploits against that particular RAS, and obtain some degree of access. They will then leverage a second set of [Escalation of Privledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) attacks in an attempt to gain unfettered access to the system. These attacks can be automated, so that they can scale to quite a degree.

More disturbing are application service (daemon) and application based attacks. Any service accessible to the outside world presents an attackable surface area, attempting to exploit flaws in the service stack, or its configuration. A service is essentially a means for a remote user to send commands and input to your server, and request it take action in response, so the reality is, that almost any daemon has some exploitable vulnerability.

Applications standing atop a service stack are the most common attack surface. Attacks against web-services like [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), [Pathing exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization), etc (essentially any input mechanism can be leveraged, including cookies, urls, input controls, etc) are often used to gain access to the underlying service, and ultimately the server OS itself.

So, now that we've covered the threat landscape, Anti-Malware systems can help prevent or mitigate attacks in a number of ways. In particular to servers, the inclusion of [Appliction-aware firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_firewall), [Intrusion Detection/Prevention System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) (IDPS) and [system vulnerability detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_%28computing%29#Identifying_and_removing_vulnerabilities) (VDS) are particularly important.

Application firewalls and Intrusion detection systems are specialized to monitor for event thresholds, and often have an understanding of the service they protect, and can thus provide advanced detections and responses to input that is malicious for the service in question but would otherwise appear to be innocuous. For instance the common utility [Fail2Ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban) works with [IPTables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables), and detects failed login attempts to services like SSH. It can be configured such that if a user fails to login 3 times in a period of time, their IP address will be blocked completely, and unblocked automatically later (if desired). This allows an application specific event to trigger a system wide response to protect against all further attacks by that user.

System vulnerability detectors use threat/vulnerability/software version databases to detect vulnerable software, and assist the user in fixing the issue. They can also detect insecure configurations, and recommend solutions to secure the vulnerability.

Traditional file/process/memory signature and heuristic detections also have their place in the grand scheme of things. They can detect jailbreak software used to escalate services as it is downloaded or compiled, detect illicit RAS/Root kits and configurations added by attackers with partial access, and protect from worm-type malware.

Modern server-grade anti-malware platforms implement components like these to varying degrees. In Linux, you usually roll your own by implementing components as needed for the services you provide (if you use SSH, install fail2ban). For Windows or other systems likely to run multiple services, suites of tools attempt to provide comprehensive protection.

So, in sum, the different workflows require both traditional and non-traditional defensive techniques in combination to protect systems.